# How to style Input Tag of ng-autocomplete pakage?

Tags: angular

I am using the below package for Autocomplete Features.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete

As shown for styling we can override!

```
.ng-autocomplete {
    width: 400px;
}
```

I want to style the HTML Input tag :
Let's say I want to set different font size, family, etc.

By overriding .ng-autocomplete doesn't style inside the input tag.

How to achieve this?
Please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Input styles are probably overwritten by something more targeted on the `input`. If you want to target the input in the specific `div` you can use the code below:

```
.ng-autocomplete input {
    // your styles here
}
```

If the Class is applied on the `input` tag itself you can try overwriting it with an `!important` flag, like so:

```
.ng-autocomplete {
    width: 400px !important;
}
```